# Pandas how to split one column in two using separator

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataframe in which one column corresponds to credit card numbers in this form:

123456******1234

I want to create two new columns: 'First' and 'Last' using the sep "******"

I have tried:

```
df[['First','Last']] = df['credit_card'].str.split("******",expand=True)
```

and get:

```
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Note: All values in the series are uniform in lenght, not NaNs

I solved in this way, but I'm interested in a more practicall and fast approach

```
for x in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[x,'bin'] = str(df.loc[x,6]).split("******")[0]
    df.loc[x,'last_four'] = str(df.loc[x,6]).split("******")[1]
```

Comment: try df.credit_card.str.split([\*]+') since the * is repeated several times. note the backslash to treat the * as a normal entry

Comment: I get sintax error with your approach @sammywemmy

Comment: Yeah, I should have added the r prefix to the code. Barmar's answer should suffice

Answer (score 4):

The delimiter is being treated as a regular expression, and `*` has special meaning in regexp, so it needs to be escaped to match literally. You can write

```
df[['First','Last']] = df['credit_card'].str.split(r"\*{6}",expand=True)
```

`{6}` means to repeat the pattern 6 times, which is shorter than writing `\*\*\*\*\*\*`